# Memory leak dyld dlopen

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, iphone-sdk-3.0, osx-snow-leopard, dyld

I am getting leak and I cannot detect from where this is happening. The stack trace does not give full info after dyld open. For few leaks I am not getting any stack trace info. All I get is only object memory address. Is anyone else facing the same issue. I am using XCode 3.2 on show leopard.

```
18  0x103038
17  0x1033c7
16  0x1034a1
15  0x90145f48
14 dyld dlopen
13 dyld dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&)
12 dyld ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&)
11 dyld ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&)
10 dyld dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*)
 9 dyld dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&)
 8 dyld dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >*)
 7 dyld dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >*)
 6 dyld dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >*)
 5 dyld dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >*)
 4 dyld dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >*)
 3 dyld dyld::mkstringf(char const*, ...)
 2 dyld strdup
 1 dyld mallocenter
```

Comment: Not knowing how you've written your code makes it very difficult to give you any suggestions.  Typically Instruments gives you a little more insight into the leak, and combining that info with your code, it is easier to track down the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing very similar behavior in xcode 3.2. The dyld leak, that didn't appear in xcode 3.1.x, and I'm not seeing anything other than a memory address for any other leaks. Just to prove I wasn't crazy, I instantiated several UILabels using alloc and didn't release them. Sure enough, xcode shows UILabel leaks, but the stacktrace is only memory addresses. In 3.1.x I used to see a stack that was much more meaningful, complete with class names. Is this a bug in the new xcode?